# Using 2SXC behind a reverse prox

Tags: iis, dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

We use 2sxc 16.07 and we add today a reverse proxy between internet and the DNN IIS website. The reverse proxy use CertBot to encrypt in HTTPS. Between the Reverse Proxy and the IIS website, the traffic is HTTP (80)
We have issue because of the replaceState witch deny mix https and http
Before the migration all works fine because HTTPS was directly managed by IIS

[image]

Try many test without solution